# Get Values from grafana from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, grafana

I am monitoring grafana dashboard with viewer permission.

Now I have to send reports of recent values of some graphs by placing cursor at the end and note down the values. I want to automate that, I have tried accessing api but no permissions.

I want to get values by injecting some javascript through console, but didn't found anything.

By moving cursor values are visible, so is there a way to move cursor at the end of the graph and get values?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to fetch the values directly from the source instead? If you have a Graphite server as the data source you could use that API instead, retrieving the same data transformations/aggregations that you specify through Grafana.

Comment: yes, but my data is already loaded in browser. So i don't want to hit API again, I am trying to get it those using js or JQuery. For every graph menu it has download csv option, I want to get the data from that.